# Error Redirect and upload photo

Tags: php, codeigniter

Having an interesting time trying to get an upload to work.  So here's the thing: I have a form that uses some javascript to pretend it's 3 separate pages.  It's all one form, but as you click "next" one section fades away and another section is shown.  The last page is the page where you can make the most errors....if you miss a required field or you're trying to sign up with an already used email address the app will kick out an error, but it has to do a:

```
redirect(/path/to/app#!section2);
```

to show the correct page where the error is located.  I can get all the data back, by quickly putting all the variables into a flashvar.  So IF this redirect were to happen I have all the data to show back in the form....except....if you tried to upload a photo, I've lost the photo upload.  My first thought was to try and save the $_FILES data to a flashvar, but I don't think that will work.

Anyone see this before?  There has to be a way around this.

Thanks

Comment: my quick and dirty solution is to, no matter what, upload the image, and save the name of the image into a flashvar...if it errors b/c of something else, on the next time through, you just stick the name into the DB (I'm not storing the image in the DB, just a path to the image)

Comment: Seems that you are trying to post data from php to flashvar  then it is quite possibly but can't do vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I would make the entire process ajax based so you wouldn't have to worry about preserving data through redirects. You could do all of your validation in your controllers as usual and then either return json or javascript code back to the browser to parse and handle what to do next.